# htaccess redirecting http://(www.)old.com and https://(www.)old.com to https://new

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am migrating a site over to a new domain, and whilst doing moving the entire site over onto https. I need the following scenarios to all redirect to https://new.com

http://old.com, https://old.com, http://www.old.com, https://www.old.com, http://new.com, http://www.new.com, https://www.new.com

I have been trying to work this out all afternoon and can get some scenarios working, but other not all. My code at the moment looks like this....

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.new\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't work for https://(www.)old.com. and http://(www.)old.com gets redirected to http://new.com.

Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use a multitude of checks if the request was made against any of the “wrong” domains, check it for whether it was *not* made against the single right one.

```
# if request was not made against new.com,
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^new\.com$ [OR]
# or if the request was not made via HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# redirect to https://new.com/…
RewriteRule (.*) https://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is simple and elegant and looks like it should work but for some reason https://(www.)old.com is still not redirecting. I am wondering whether there is some caching going on, because it seems to be defying logic.

Comment: Could be a caching issue – can you try in a different browser to verify?

Comment: And of course you still need a valid SSL certificate for `(www.)old.com`, otherwise the request will not even make it to the stage where you _could_ do a redirect. That the case?

Comment: That is the problem. The server will only allow one SSL certificate, so we have installed one for new.com and had to remove the one for old.com. That is going to be a problem!

Comment: Then you’ll either have to get an SSL Cert that includes old.com and www.old.com as [Subject Alternative Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName); or move the old.com domain to a different server, so that server can present a valid certificate for (www.)old.com, and then redirect to new.com from there.

Comment: I will speak to the hosting company tomorrow and see what they can offer. Thanks for all your help.